# Date format from "01/03/2000" to "datetime.datetime(2000, 3, 1, 0, 0)"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hi Guys how do i convert CSV file date format from "01/03/2000" to "datetime.datetime(2000, 3, 1, 0, 0)" date column has to be converted in to  this "datetime.datetime(2000, 3, 1, 0, 0)" format

```
    apl = pd.read_csv('Data_Resource/aapl.csv')
    print(apl.head())
    Unnamed: 0  adj_close   close        date    high     low    open   volume
0           0      31.68  130.31  2000-03-01  132.06  118.50  118.56  38478000
1           1      29.66  122.00  2000-03-02  127.94  120.69  127.00  11136800
2           2      31.12  128.00  2000-03-03  128.23  120.00  124.87  11565200
3           3      30.56  125.69  2000-03-06  129.13  125.00  126.00  7520000
```

date

```
    [datetime.datetime(2000, 3, 1, 0, 0),
    datetime.datetime(2000, 3, 2, 0, 0),
    datetime.datetime(2000, 3, 3, 0, 0),
    datetime.datetime(2000, 3, 6, 0, 0),
```

Comment: what is your desired output for the date column?

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```